# RE Match each word with a part of the pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary, python-re

I think this is best illustrated with an example.

I have the RE pattern `choco_icecream = "(do|does) \w+ (loves|love|likes|like) (choco|chocolate) (ice-cream|icecream|ice cream)"`.
I want to check if `example = "Does Jessica like Chocolate Icecream".lower()` is a match for `choco_icecream`.

The `example` is a match of `choco_icecream`, but I want to know which word of `example` corresponds to an element of `choco_icecream`.

I would like in a dictionary. The ideal output will look like this: `{"(do|does)":"does", "\w+":"jessica", "(loves|love|likes|like)":"like", "(choco|chocolate)":"chocolate", "(ice-cream|icecream|ice cream)":"icecream"}`

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would all have been clear if you had just played around with this a bit, along with the documentation.

```
import re

choco_icecream = "(do|does) (\w+) (loves|love|likes|like) (choco|chocolate) (ice-cream|icecream|ice cream)"
example = "Does Jessica like Chocolate Icecream".lower()

x = re.match(choco_icecream, example)
print(x)
print(x.groups())
```

Output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 36), match='does jessica like chocolate icecream'>
('does', 'jessica', 'like', 'chocolate', 'icecream')
```

Printing the whole `match` object gives you the entire match, but every set of parentheses you have in your expression creates a new "group", and the groups are all returned individually.

Note that I modified your regex to make the name a group as well.